# select `specific name` or `all` from a table

Tags: php, mysql

Now I'm calling `taman section` from a table,I want to call only specific taman section or call all of the `taman section` inside the table,how could I do that?
Bellow are my code:

post.php:

```
<select name="taman">
<option value="taman1">Taman1</option>
<option value="tamanA">TamanA</option>
<option value="*">ALL</option>
</select>
```

select.php

```
$taman = $_POST["taman"]; //this taman are post from post.php,I have tried put value * to this $taman, but still cannot.

$qry="SELECT cusinfo.* FROM cusinfo 
                        WHERE cusinfo.TAMAN_SECTION = '$taman'
                        ";
```

Comment: put a `name=""` attribute on the `<select>` tag, and don't forget to put the `method=""` type on the `<form>` tag as well

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try this

```
$taman = $_POST["taman"]; 
if($taman=='*'){
$qry="SELECT cusinfo.* FROM cusinfo ";                   
}
else{
$qry="SELECT cusinfo.* FROM cusinfo WHERE cusinfo.TAMAN_SECTION = '".$taman."'"; 
}
```

Here no need to change the html select option.